# Replace identical lines with just one line at end in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Can I replace identical lines with just one line at the end in Notepad++? E.g. from:

```
1st January 2013
//some text1
1st January 2013
//some text2
1st January 2013
//some text3
1st January 2013
```

to:

```
//some text1
//some text2
//some text3
1st January 2013
```

Also is it possible, if I have all dates from 1 to 30 or 31, to replace them individually at their last appearance?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this regex in the search and replace dialogue:

```
^(.*?)$\s+?^(?=.*^\1$)
```

and replace with nothing.

You need to check the options "Regular expression" and ". matches newline":

[image: Notepad++ Replace dialogue]

Regex explanation:

`^` matches the start of the row

`(.*?)` matches any characters 0 or more as few as possible. The matched row is stored, because of the brackets around and accessible using `\1`

`$` matches the end of the row

`\s+?^` this part matches all whitespace characters (newlines!) till the next Start of the row ==> This removes the newlines

`(?=.*^\1$)` this is a positive lookahead assertion. This is the important part in this regex, a row is only matched (and removed), when there is exactly the same row following somewhere else in the file.

Comment: Much simpler expression than what I had! The lookahead will erroneously match if the line it's looking for is an ending substring of a subsequent line though (since the . matches all will consume the beginning of a line)

Comment: @DarthAndroid, thanks for the hint, fixed by adding anchors around the back reference.

Comment: @stema I tried your solution but it isn`t working.
I noticed there is difference between screenshot expression and written one.

`^(.*?)$\s+?^(?=.*^\1$)`    vs  `^(.*?)$\s+^(?=.*^\1)`


I tried both of them also part by part
it works till `^(.*?)$` i.e selection of whole line.
But when I add `\s` next to it,npp selects rows containing and upto  `$`

I have selected Regular expression.

Comment: also what changes should be made to match rows containing numbers in this case dates or year to avoid removing duplicate rows having characters.

Comment: @astroboy, have you also checked the second option ". matches newline"? For me both expressions work with your example text (The new one is only covering special case that a row ends with something that has been a row on its own)

Comment: funny thing is you are right it is working on my sample text...
but not on my **original** text. It's a html file with around 4200 lines..It erases whole text and says 1 or 3 occurrences removed...

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this Sublime Text 2 (or any editor with full regex support - NOT Notepad++, sadly) with regex find & replace.

Find:

```
^(([^\n]+\n)*)([^\n]+)\n(([^\n]+\n)*)\3(\n.*)*$
```

Replace:

```
\1\4\3\6
```

Keep clicking "replace" until duplicate lines have been removed from the document. "Replace All" won't work here (or you'll have to press it multiple times).

---

Found a simpler solution that works for Notepad++ as well as other editors. Find with Regular expression mode and disable ". matches newline":

```
^(.*)$\s+(?=(^.*$\s+)*\1)
```

And replace with nothing. This is based off of @stema's answer below, but works even when the matched lines are substrings of following lines:

```
1st January 2013
//some text1
1st January 2013
//some text2
1st January 2013
//some text3
21st January 2013
```

Should properly return

```
//some text1
//some text2
1st January 2013
//some text3
21st January 2013
```

Comment: Try a current Notepad++ version, since Version 6 it supports PCRE and no, this has nothing to do with sorcery.

Comment: @stema Using version 6.1.3 and the above expression does not work out of the box, though it works in my other editors. Found a simpler solution that works even for Notepad++, though.

Answer (score 0):

Scanning for duplicate lines is, as far as I know, not possible in Notepad++ without any plugins, although you can make a manual effort a lot easier if the duplicates have a known format. For instance, dates formatted as '3rd February 2012' can be easily found (and replaced by empty strings) by matching against the regular expression `^\d+[snrt][tdh] [A-Z][a-z]* 20\d\d$`.

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958350/removing-duplicate-rows-in-notepad/3958364#3958364) does a great job explaining, the plugin TextFX is particularly useful for these procedures through its ability to temporarily sort lines.